# mvc how to submit a viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently want a user to update a list of data and be able to submit it back.
The data the user is updating are similar data, at the moment it is a a handful of textboxes.  They update the information and submit it back.

At the moment I have created the following viewModel

```
public class Name
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

This will hold the data.  So from the controller I am mocking the data at the moment

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var listOfNames = new List<Name>();

    var name1 = new Name();
    name1.Id = 1;
    name1.FullName = "Test Name1";

    var name2 = new Name();
    name2.Id = 2;
    name2.FullName = "Test Name2";

    var name3 = new Name();
    name3.Id = 3;
    name3.FullName = "Test Name3";

    var name4 = new Name();
    name4.Id = 4;
    name4.FullName = "Test Name4";

    listOfNames.Add(name1);
    listOfNames.Add(name2);
    listOfNames.Add(name3);
    listOfNames.Add(name4);

    return View(listOfNames);
}
```

Then the view looks like the following,

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Name>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.TextBox("namevalues", item.FullName, new { id = "name" + item.Id, data_id = item.Id})
    <br />
    }

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

when the user submits the data I would like to have the viewmodel back populated, so that I should be able to do the following

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Name> names)
{

    return View("index", names);
}
```

Do I need to use javascript to actually collate the info together then pass that? or is there some MVC magic I don't know about?

Comment: You don't need JavaScript to do what you need. Just bind a view model to your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you do not need JavaScript. You can use a view model that you can bind to your view. I don't like to pass domain models to the view, I prefer a view model that is much more scaled down with regards to data. It could like this:

```
public class NameListViewModel
{
     public List<Name> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to populate the list of names in your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     NameListViewModel viewModel = new NameListViewModel();
     viewModel.Names = new List<Name>();
     viewModel.Names.Add(new Name { Id = 1, FullName = "Test Name1" });
     viewModel.Names.Add(new Name { Id = 2, FullName = "Test Name2" });
     viewModel.Names.Add(new Name { Id = 3, FullName = "Test Name3" });
     viewModel.Names.Add(new Name { Id = 4, FullName = "Test Name4" });

     return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(NameListViewModel viewModel)
{
     // All the values should still be in viewModel
     // Do whatever you need to do
}
```

And then on your view you can use an array of text boxes like this:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Names.NameListViewModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Names.Count(); i++)
{
     <div>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Names[i].FullName)
          @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Names[i].FullName)
     </div>
}
```

Try it and see if it works. Modify the code to fit in with your scenario and do the rest that you need.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have a solution too with minimum changes. But, can you explain the reason why not `IEnumerable` ?

Comment: I used `List` in this example because it has a `count` property. If I don't need count then I normally use `IEnumerable`. Personal choice. Use what you feel comfortable with.

Comment: let me explain so that we are on the same track...In the OP's question, `IEnumerable` is used and OP could not figure out why the View Model value is null in *Post Action Method*. can you explain what the issue was in his code. I am not saying that there is some issue in using List. Instead I am trying to learn why `IEnumerable` is not posting the View Model. I too tried IEnumerable in my sample app and same problem at my end. I could also use `List` **but that's an alternative**.

Comment: Lists normally come back as null on post backs. By binding them my way they will come back with data. I used List because it has a count property.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Do you have any idea why `IEnumerable` post null to Post Action Method when posting list object ?

Comment: yeah I would prefer to use IEnumerable as well, but that will not work, as you cannot index the ienumerable with the [i] notation.  You have to convert it to an actual concrete type, that is why a list works.  That's my understanding anyway.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FullName)` the property would be bound to the text box. Now it is just a text box with content.

Comment: how can I use x=>x.Fullname? can you please show me all the code? would I still need to use a foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an array of text boxes in your HTML.

Take a look at this for some info on how to do this in MVC: 
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: Yes I agree with you, you need to use arrays. I provided some decent sample code.

Comment: @havardhu : Why array and why not `IEnumerable`? What's the problem with `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @BrendanVogt : Please check my above query.

Comment: @PKKG I am talking about an array of HTML input fields, not .NET arrays. The solution I referred to is a different approach than what BrendanVogt posted. TBH I'd go with his solution, using the view model

Answer (score -1):

Try Using

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.FullName, new { id = "name" + item.Id, data_id = item.Id });`

instead of

`@Html.TextBox("namevalues", item.FullName, new { id = "name" + item.Id, data_id = item.Id})`

Comment: I am getting a compliation error, so I changed it to  @Html.TextBoxFor(item.FullName) but it is still the same.  Any thoughts?